# How can i define a different order of my unit tests?

Tags: c#, selenium, unit-testing

I have these 3 tests:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace FirstTestCase
{
class _04_02_Media
{

    class NUnitTest
    {
[TestCase(TestName = "04_02_01_Libraries_Add_OnDemand_Video")]
                public void Libraries()
                {}
    [TestCase(TestName = "04_02_02_Replace_OnDemand")]
                public void OnDemandReplace()
                {}
    [TestCase(TestName = "04_02_03_Delete_OnDemand")]
                public void OnDemandDelete()
                {}
```

For some reason i cannot understand and is making me go crazy, the "delete" test, the one supposed to be the last, happens second.
This is a big deal as the "replace" test, that happens last, uses the deleted video.

Why does it run in this order? Is there anything else i should use to change the order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`Order`](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/order.html) attribute to specify the order:

```
[Order(1)]
public void Test1() { /* ... */ }

[Order(2)]
public void Test2() { /* ... */ }

[Order(3)]
public void Test3() { /* ... */ }
```

However, you should really try to make sure your tests are self-contained otherwise they can be quite brittle.

Comment: Last line should be bold ;)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. One question, any specific library i need to be using for [Order]? VS doesnt seem to understand how to use it.

Should it go before the [testCase] or inside it?

Comment: @DjNewma I linked directly to the library, it's part of NUnit which you seem to be using.

Comment: @DavidG Using [Order(x)] before [TestCase...] i get a compiler error CS0246 -  The type or namespace name 'OrderAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). I am using Nunit already. (Nunit.Framework and adding "using NUnit" does not work

Comment: @DavidG It does not, it does not exist according to VS.

Comment: @DjNewma Which version of NUnit are you using? Have you tried restarting VS?

Comment: @DavidG, after replying i checked the version and i did need to update to V3.13.2 and also updated Nunit3TestAdapter to v4.0.0. I have also restarted VS, several times. Still unsuccessful

Comment: [OrderAttribute](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/order.html) is available since nunit 3.2

Comment: @DjNewma I have nothing else to say, it does work, and here is proof https://dotnetfiddle.net/vTAcl1

Comment: @DavidG, thank you for the help. I will keep looking into this and update if i find the solution. Cheers

Comment: @DavidG I decided to re-install the NUnit plugin and it is now working. Thank you very much. Marking it as the solution

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`order`](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/order.html) attribute.

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace FirstTestCase
{
    class _04_02_Media
    {

        class NUnitTest
        {
            [Test, Order(1)]
            public void Libraries()
            {}

            [Test, Order(2)]
            public void OnDemandReplace()
            {}

            [Test, Order(3)]
            public void OnDemandDelete()
            {}
        }
    }
}
```